# JavaScript ожидание появления ссылки

Tags: javascript

У меня есть три строчки JavaScript кода.

```
document.getElementById('story').value='Troy';

document.querySelector('body > div.wrapper > div.header > div.header44 > div.search_panel > span > form > button').click();

document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].click();
```

Первая строка - выставляет названия фильма в текстовом поле
Вторая строка - нажимает кнопку "Найти"
Третья строка - после результата поиска, нажимает на первую ссылку

Эти коды мне необходимо запустить в консоли браузера. Если их запускать каждую по отдельности, то все работает прекрасно. Но мне нужно запустить все три строчки одним скриптом.
Первые две строки должны сработать сразу же, а третья строчка должна дождаться появления нужной мне ссылки (которую я указал в коде), а потом кликнуть по ней.
Как мне реализовать задумку для третьей строчки?

Comment: promise - слышали про такое?

Comment: Нет я не силен в JavaScript, помогите пожалуйста мне реализовать эту задумку

Comment: В javascript последовательное написание кода не означает, что Ваши инструкции будут выполнены в той же последовательности.

Comment: promise - это тема кажется очень огромной. не могли бы вы мне помочь с написанием моего кода?

Comment: promise не помогло................ const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].click(), 3000);
  });

Comment: Ваш скрипт напоминает пользовательский скрипт(user script), не могли бы вы сказать доменное имя сайта на котором должен запускаться скрипт?